# facebook group members Bio information

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am interested in retrieving a Facebook group members' **Bio**  information.

I have created an app where I have requested permission of about **user_about_me** and the app is under review for submission.

I have coded for the app in JSP but it can only select **name, gender, last_name, first_name** only. It is not selecting the **Bio** information.

I face the same problem even in the graph API explorer, when I use

```
{group_ID}/members
```

I can retrieve list of all group members. But I can not see more details than the following:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "name", 
      "administrator": false, 
      "id": "USER ID"
    },
    ..
```

When I click on the ID (or enter the ID in the explorer), I can only get the following:

```
{
   "id": "member_ID", 
   "first_name": "firstname", 
   "last_name": "lastname", 
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/...", 
   "name": "name  ", 
   "updated_time": "2015-02-07T10:02:58+0000" 
}
```

This is not showing the **Bio** information.
when I enter the following:

```
 {member_ID}?fields=bio
```

I just get

```
{
  "id": "10153223503039309"
}
```

I will appreciate if someone please identify me the problem. I believe this problem will also solve my code problem, where at the moment I am unable to retrieve the group member's Bio information too.

Is it possible that the problem will be resolved after the app's acceptance, which is under review?

Thanks you very much.

Syed

Answer (score 1):

You can´t just grab more information from the user just because he is a member of some group. You would have to let him [authorize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) your App with the correct permissions in order to get more data.

Comment: Thanks. Those members of the group have already authorized the app by through a webpage that use javascript SDK. The app also appears in their facebook account along with other apps they use. I have submitted the app for approval. Do you think once facebook approve the app, that will then allow the Bio section appear in results.

Comment: no, you can only retrieve additional information with an access token of that user

Comment: Thanks. Plz guide me. How can I get permission from all members of that group for their Bio information. Through the [Javascript code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2), I can only ask for permission from one user being logged in about his own Bio information only. Now, what is the way to get permission from all members of that group? What I require is that whenever any member of that specific Facebook group login to my website/app, he should view Bio of all members of that group. How I can get the needed permissions in this case from all members?

Comment: you can´t just grab it from all members. as i said, you would have to authorize every single user. how to do that is explained very well in the facebook docs.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Can you please just share with me just one link from anywhere on the web.. or what portion of the facebook docs. may be I am missing it. I have checked a lot they all talk about permissions from individual facebook users. I have posted another [question]((http://stackoverflow.com/q/29084985/2794895)) about this specific help.

Comment: this is a good tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/